# JavaScript OOP: Uncaught TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Have trouble with object creation. Console says that something wrong in the last line. Please tell how it should be, I more familar with Java, so this is little bit confusing for me.

```
var dog = {
        name:"Dog",
        age:"11",
        getName : function() {
            alert(this.name);       
        }
    }   

    function Dog(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age; 
    }

    var d1 = new Dog("Rex", 8);
    d1.getName();
```

Comment: Why do you expect `d1` to have a `getName()` function? The object you declare and assign to the variable `dog` has nothing at all to do with the instance created from the function `Dog()`.

Comment: `dog` doesn't become the prototype of `Dog` miraculously

Comment: @Ponty ok, how it should be, please

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve. The *problem* is that a `Dog()` instance won't have a `.getName()` method. You can add one in the constructor or add one to the `Dog()` prototype.

Comment: @Pointy I'm trying to create class 'Dog', with fields 'name' and 'age' and method 'getName' and create constructor, then I'm trying to get name of created object.

Comment: I recommend to a read a tutorial, such as [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) or [The Secret Life of Objects](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional OO in JavaScript

```
function Dog(name, age) {
    this.name = name || "Dog";// if the name is not given, it defaults to "Dog"
    this.age = age || "11"; 
}

Dog.prototype.getName =  function() {
    alert(this.name); 
}

var d1 = new Dog("Rex", 8);
d1.getName();
```

More Explicit OO in JavaScript

```
function createDog(name, age) {
    // create a new dog and return it
    var dog = {
        name: name || "Dog",// if the name is not given, it defaults to "Dog"
        age: age || "11"
    };
    return dog;
}

createDog.getName =  function(dog) {
    // explicit dog as 1st parameter
    alert(dog.name); 
}

//createDog is a normal function that returns something, no "new" needed
var d1 = createDog("Rex", 8);
createDog.getName(d1);
```

Comment: i.e. I should declare fields of class through constructor ?

Comment: In JavaScript, objects are like dynamic structs, you can add and change fields, at runtime. In general it is a good idea to declare them in the constructor, but it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your `dog` is just a simple Object literal,
that means that your `getName` is bound to it, not to your `Dog` *class*.

You can make that function a `method` of `Dog` instead:

```js
/*var dog = {
  name:"Dog",
  age:"11",
  getName : function() {
    alert(this.name);       
  }
}*/ 

function Dog(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age; 
}

Dog.prototype.getName = function() {
  console.log( this.name );
}

var d1 = new Dog("Rex", 8);
d1.getName(); // "Rex"
```

Here's a variant that uses your `settings` "defaults"

```js
function Dog() {
  this.name = "Dog"; // Default name
  this.age = 11;     // Default age
}

Dog.prototype.getName = function() {
  console.log( this.name );
}

var d1 = new Dog();
d1.name = "Rex";    // Override default name
d1.getName(); // "Rex"
```

Comment: So I should not include methods in{ } and use .prototype. instead ?

Comment: and how should I declare fields then ?

Comment: @GeorgeJ see my second example

Comment: As I understand from 1st example I can declare fields using only constructor ,right ?

Comment: Why did you remove settings from example with settings ?

Comment: @GeorgeJ cause it's not an ideal way to build stuff! Use the second example instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **class** with syntaxic sugar to properly create objects in ES6.
In your exemple that would write like this :

```
'use strict';
class Dog{
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  getName(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

let doggy = new Dog("krypto", 125);
doggy.getName();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid not all people use latest browsers, so would be nice to clarify this questing using old-style syntax.